# How to remove duplicated rows in excel when there is certain matching values

Tags: excel

I want to delete all the rows that contains duplicates in specefic columns.

So for example, If there's row 1 and 2, and both of them have the same values in column B and E, then I want the duplicates to be deleted by row.

Does it make sens? English isn't my first langage so it's hard to put in word what I want. Thank you all.

For example, the first row should be deleted only despited having the same value 3 times in "numero du certificat..."

[image]

Comment: On the data tab there is a Remove Duplicates that allows you to dictate which columns of the selected range to use to determine which are duplicates.  It will leave the first instance of the duplicates and remove the rest.

Comment: @ScottCraner does it remove the duplicated values individualy by column, or does it evaluate if the values in a, b and c are repeated in the next rows, and then deleted the entire rows?

Comment: It will remove the entire row of the chosen range.  So you would choose the whole data range, select Remove Duplicates.  Then choose the two column that you want to use as the reference, and it will delete the full row of all the chosen columns.

Comment: Make a copy of your data and play with it.